# Is there any way to improve ability score without items, only with spells or class features?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, statistics

I found a few, but they are all bad, like true polymorph to improve ability scores (but I lose class features), does someone know any way to improve ability scores without losing class features, and without using magical items, only spells and class shenanigans?
temporary and permanent increases are welcome
my objective is improve warlock damage from lifedrinker